# Proving a certain limit is 0 given that the function is differentiable at that limit point

Tags: calculus, limits

This is a homework problem, by the way.

> Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is differentiable at $x = 0$. Prove that $$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x^2) - f(0)}{x} = 0$$

To say that $f$ is differentiable at $x = 0$ means that by the limit definition of the derivative, the limit $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0}$ exists. However, I'm not sure where to proceed from here, or how that might help me prove the proposition.

Comment: Multiply the top and bottom by  $x$ (can do this as $x \neq 0$). Now, use the fact that $x^2$ is continuous, and $f$ is continuous, by taking a new  variable $y = x^2$ in the differential quotient.

Answer (score 2):

Note $f(x^2)=(f\circ g)(x)$ with $g(x):=x^2$ and $g(x)$ is a differentiable function. Moreover $g(0)=0$ and $(f\circ g)(x)$ is differentiable at $0$. Let $h(x):=f(x^2)$ then 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x^2)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{h(x)-h(0)}{x}=h'(0)$$
But $h'(0)=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)\Big|_{x=0}=f'(x^2)\cdot2x\Big|_{x=0}=f'(0)\cdot 0=0$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(x^{2})-f(0)}{x}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(x^{2})-f(0)}{x^{2}}\cdot x\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(x^{2})-f(0)}{x^{2}}\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\\
&=f'(0)\cdot 0\\
&=0.
\end{align*}